# Is there any way to release (clean) static fields

Tags: android

Is there any way to release(clean) static fields ect. Singletons or constant values when exit Android app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign the fields of types that extend Object to null.
This way, if there are no more references they can be collected by GC.

The primitive types will be released only when their owner class Object is collected.

Answer (score 6):

When an Android application exits, all of its data is released. You can release the fields also by simply assiging `null` to them.

Answer (score 1):

No I dont think there's any other way except assigning individual variables to null ,release your resources in the onStop() or onPause()